# Testing Javascript files that uses typescript module in Jest and React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am currently adding a Typescript component into a legacy Javascript component and found errors when testing the Javascript component that imports/uses a Typescript component. Here are the error printed by Jest

```
 Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.
```

Here are my jest.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "jsx", "ts", "tsx"],
  preset: "ts-jest",
  collectCoverage: true,
  // collectCoverage: false,
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/", "/old/"],
  coverageReporters: ["html", "json", "lcov", "text", "text-summary"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$":
      "<rootDir>/src/infrastructure/utils/test/mocks.js",
    "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "<rootDir>/src/infrastructure/utils/test/mocks.js",
  },
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src"],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/setupTests.js"],
  testMatch: ["**/*.(test|spec).(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/(?!(react-leaflet)|react-leaflet|@react-leaflet)"],
  verbose: true,
  // maxWorkers: 30,
  exclude: ["node_modules"],
};
```

and here are my tsconfig

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
        "paths": {
            "application": ["./src/application"],
            "infrastructure": ["./src/infrastructure"],
            "main": ["./src/main"],
            "mobile": ["./src/mobile"],
            "presentation": ["./src/presentation"],
            
        }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "setupTests copy.js", "global.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

and babel config

```js
module.exports = { presets: ['@babel/preset-env', "@babel/preset-react"] };
```

Any help would be awesome, thanks!